# Checking whether all tasks in ThreadPoolExecutor are completed

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

How can I check whether all tasks submitted to `ThreadPoolExecutor` are completed?

New tasks can be added from previously submitted tasks, so I can't call `shutdown` followed by `awaitTermination` nor `invokeAll`, as it will ignore these new tasks.

Comment: Related but different problem so not quite a dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929361/how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-in-an-threadpoolexecutor-to-finish-without-shutting-do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`yourThreadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount();` will return 0 when all tasks have completed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount%28%29).

Comment: I have a flacky test that may be related to using this. Reading the documenttion states that this number is an aproximation: "Returns the approximate number of threads that are actively executing tasks".

Answer (score 1):

You can use ThreadPoolExecutor.getCompletedTaskCount()