# Why is Pool count increasing for Executor Service Implementation?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a java program deployed in Weblogic server which is executed using Quartz scheduler. The program executes in every 10 seconds. In the java code I have created two threads using ExcutorService and I have called service.shutdown() at the end. But every time the quartz scheduler runs the program it creates a new pool of threads by incrementing the pool id like "pool-109-thread-1" and "pool-109-thread-2" then pool-110-thread-1" and "pool-110-thread-2". So this pool count is increasing. Is it ok or do I need to change something in my code ?
Sample Code below:`

```
public void post(){
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    for (String filePath : strArray) {
service.submit(new PostImages(postURL,filePath)); 
}
service.shutDown();
}
```

`

Comment: you shouldn't be initializing `ExecutorService` everytime.

Comment: Ok but what happens to the old thread pool in my code ? And why is the pool count increasing for every execution of the post() method ? Is service.shutdown() not working ?

Comment: Hi Xersis : When do you call post() method? Move this statement out of post() method.  ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); Call shutDown() method in some other place.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call the `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)` a new thread pool of 2 threads is created. It will be a problem if running too much times because the number of process of your OS will crash.

You must to convert your local variable to a static variable and to have only 1 instance of this thread pool, keeping only 2 threads to execute the jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this is what you want to use

If you are interested in knowing when a certain task completes, or a certain batch of tasks, you may use `ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)`. Invoking this method returns a `Future` object which may be placed into a `Collection` which your main thread will then iterate over calling `Future.get()` for each one. This will cause your main thread to halt execution until the `ExecutorService` has processed all of the `Runnable` tasks.

```
Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<Future<?>>();
futures.add(executorService.submit(myRunnable));
for (Future<?> future:futures) {
    future.get();
}
```

[How to wait for all tasks in an ThreadPoolExecutor to finish without shutting down the Executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929361/how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-in-an-threadpoolexecutor-to-finish-without-shutting-do)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's ok. It's probably incrementing the pool ID because old ones are still waiting for the garbage collector.

Comment: Hi Leo.. For test I redeployed the war in weblogic environment and surprisingly the pool ID again got incremented. Earlier it was 'pool-309-thread-1' and after redeployment it started from 'pool-310-thread-1'. Is it still ok ? or is there seriously something wrong ? Please help !!

Comment: @Xerxis did you find the reason behind this? I am facing a similar situation where threadpool count is increasing everytime.