# add values into global set from different threads and wait for all the threads to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, set, threadpool, executorservice

I mam new to Threading, Was wondering if I could split huge data into small tasks using threads, so that the time for processing is reduced
I have split the Set into multiple list of sets and each thread from executor service takes up the set and addes the set into another set(globally declared) **abcSet**.
I need each threads to add objects into this set and after all the threads finish adding, continue with the rest of the job that has to be done with **abcSet**
below is the sample code. Help Please!!

```
private static final int PARTITIONS_COUNT = 4;
final Set<Abc> newAbcSet = new HashSet<Abc>();
final Set<Abc> abcSet = //data from database
        ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
List<Set<Abc>> theSets = new ArrayList<Set<Abc>>(PARTITIONS_COUNT);
// divide set into 4 different sets for threading purpose
for (int i = 0; i < PARTITIONS_COUNT; i++) {
    theSets.add(new HashSet<Abc>());
}

int index = 0;
for (Abc abcObj : abcSet) {
    theSets.get(index++ % PARTITIONS_COUNT).add(abcObj);
}
for (final Set<Abc> abcSet1 : theSets) {
    e.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (Abc abc : abcSet1) {
                //do some modifications with abc and add it to newAbcSet
                newAbcSet.add(abc);
            }

        }
    });

}
//Do something with the newAbcSet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To prevent race confition, you should use a [thread safe `Set` implemention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720396/different-types-of-thread-safe-sets-in-java), for example:

  ```
  final Set<Abc> newAbcSet= Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Abc>());
  ```
- If you do not need the thread pool any more, you can just call [`shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown()) and [`awaitTermination()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

  ```
  e.shutDown();  //  previously submitted tasks are not affected
  e.awaitTermination();  // Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

  //Do something with the newAbcSet
  ```

  If the thread pool is still needed, refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929361/how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-in-an-threadpoolexecutor-to-finish-without-shutting-do).

Answer (score 1):

After `for` add `while (!e.isTerminated()){}` to stop execution:

```
for (final Set<Abc> abcSet1 : theSets) {
    e.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(Abc abc: abcSet1){
                //do some modifications with abc and add it to newAbcSet
                newAbcSet.add(abc);
            }

        }
    });
}

while (!e.isTerminated()){}
```